# how to process the kibana search result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am quite new to `kibana` and could get a response result as below

```
{message:"Sun Oct  2 21:17:13 2016 : Stat: dact: requests : 209/1759718/0, responses: 0/987213/0 , dup : 0/0/0, invalid: 0/772505/0, malformed: 0/0/0"}
```

I would like to process this result to only get the first number of requests: 209.

I am not familiar with syntax and I need the answer of process after create the index.

Answer (score 0):

If that `209/1759718/0` is a string (I think it must be) then I think you can parse that field out into a scripted field in Kibana 5.0 (release candidate 1 is available now) using a regular expresssion in the new `Painless` scripting language.

But you would have to enable regular expressions in your Elasticsearch, see;
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html

I haven't tried this myself so I'm not certain it would work...